# Web API HttpClient POST not working in .Net

Tags: .net, json, http-post, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient

I have a requirement to GET and POST data through web API call in server side

GET call is working and returing json, see below

```
Dim json As String = String.Empty
Dim client As New HttpClient()
client.BaseAddress = New Uri("http:\\example.com\test")
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(New MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))
Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = client.GetAsync("http:\\example.com\test").Result

If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
    json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
End If
```

When I am trying to do POST call below, nothing is happening

POST call accepts below json

```
{
  "messageDescription": "string",
  "effectiveStartDate": "2016-12-09",
  "effectiveEndDate": "2016-12-09",
  "isActive": "string"
}

Dim client = New HttpClient()
client.BaseAddress = New Uri("http:\\example.com\test")
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(New MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))
Dim request = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http:\\example.com\test")

Dim isActive As String = "Y"

Dim requestContent = String.Format("effectiveStartDate={0}&effectiveEndDate={1}&messageDescription={2}&isActive={3}", effectiveStartDate, effectiveEndDate, txtValue, isActive)
request.Content = New StringContent(requestContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

Dim response = client.SendAsync(request)
```

Can someone please help me in right direction

Comment: you say POST accepts JSON but then send a form-urlencoded POST request. does the target endpoint accept form-urlencoded requests? What response do you get when you send that POST

Comment: Sorry my endpoint only accepts parameter content type as "application/json". When I post data, I will receive the recently inserted record from DB. Now I am getting this message "Id = 899, Status = WaitingForActivation {1}, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}""